# Mail() SMTP Server Response Error

Tags: php, email, smtp, warnings

I'm relatively new to creating and sending email messages using php so I could use some guidance from the experts.  I've been working on an application for my web site that would allow visitors to place themselves on a mailing list to receive periodic newsletters.  As far as I can tell, it should be working. However, I get the following error message when trying to send a test message

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 554 Sending address not accepted due to spam.

From what I can see, this problem has been addressed with other questions on this site, essentially indicating that I have somehow found myself on a spamming blacklist run by my hosting server (hostgator).  I contacted their technical support group earlier today in an effort to get this resolved.  After I explained the problem to them, they asked what SMTP settings I was using.  I thought this to be a strange question as I am not sending these messages through Outlook or other email software but directly from my web site using php `mail()`.  Their solution was to provide me with a domain name to use for my incoming and outgoing mail servers as well as specific settings to use.

Here's where the confusion comes in.  I'm not sure how I can use this new information in my php code for sending an email.  Am I supposed to put some of this information into the headers accompanying the message?  As I understand it, using php `mail()` causes the message to be sent from the host servers and any changes that I make to the email software settings on my home desktop should have no effect.  Other than assuming that the individual that I spoke with at hostgator doesn't understand my question and trying to get a different answer from a different technical support specialist, I am at a loss as to what to do.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please format your question, it's very hard to read.

Comment: Edit your question so people can read it and post your code where you're having issue along with the error messages you're getting.

Comment: suggestion one is not to use php mail() is under powered, use phpmailer

Comment: rtfm - where would you suggest I look to learn more about phpmailer? Is this something that would be available on my server or is it something that has to be installed on my server? By me or my host? Is there a phpmailer for dummies book available at Borders?